# Only the first card will flip

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transforms

I want to make a photo gallery that flips the picture on click or tab, when flipped the user will get more information about the picture itself and a link. I have posted my entire CSS, JS and HTML so I hope that anyone will be able to spot my error.

JS:

```
$('#flip').on('click', function() {
    $(".card", this).toggleClass("flipped");
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="flip" class="flip">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="face front">Front</div>
        <div class="face back">Back</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="flip" class="flip">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="face front">Front</div>
        <div class="face back">Back</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.flip {
    perspective: 800;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 50px auto;
}

.flip .card.flipped {
    transform: rotatex(-180deg);
}

.flip .card {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.flip .card .face {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 2;
    font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    font-size: 3em;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 200px;
}

.flip .card .front {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    background: $da_grey;
    color: $white;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.flip .card .back {
    transform: rotatex(-180deg);
    background: #121212;
    color: $white;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: ID should be unique. Bind event on class `$('.flip').on('click', function() {
    $(".card", this).toggleClass("flipped");
});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you are duplicating `ID` value, which is supposed to be unique. Change it to:

```
<div id="flip1" class="flip">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="face front">Front</div>
        <div class="face back">Back</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="flip2" class="flip">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="face front">Front</div>
        <div class="face back">Back</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$('#flip1, #flip2').on('click', function() {
    $(".card", this).toggleClass("flipped");
});
```

It is better to use classes for this:

```
$('.flip').on('click', function() {
    $(".card", this).toggleClass("flipped");
});
```

But make sure you **don't duplicate** `ID`s.